# Best Subset regression on test sample (after k-fold)

Tags: testing, regression, subset, cross-validation, training-data

I am running a best subset regression analyses in R studio. I am using the following libraries:
    library(foreign)
    library(glmnet)
    library(caTools)
    library(leaps)
    library(ISLR)
    library(knitr)
    library(ggvis)

I want to split my sample into three samples: training, cross-validation, and test (maybe 50%, 30%, 20%).

I have successfully ran best subset on our training and cross-validated those results with the following script:

```
k = 10
set.seed(1)
folds = sample(1:k,nrow(best_demo_train),replace=TRUE)
table(folds)

cv.errors=matrix(NA,k,5, dimnames=list(NULL, paste(1:5)))

predict.regsubsets = function(object, newdata, id, ...) {
  form = as.formula(object$call[[2]])
  mat = model.matrix(form, newdata)
  coefi = coef(object, id = id)
  mat[, names(coefi)] %*% coefi
}

for(j in 1:k){
  best.fit = regsubsets(selfaware ~., data=best_demo_train[folds != j,])

  for (i in 1:5){
    pred = predict(best.fit, best_demo_train[folds == j, ], id = i)
    cv.errors[j, i] = mean((best_demo_train$selfaware[folds == j] - pred)^2)
  }
}

mean.cv.errors=apply(cv.errors,2,mean)
mean.cv.errors
which.min(mean.cv.errors)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(mean.cv.errors,type='b')
points(which.min(mean.cv.errors),mean.cv.errors[which.min(mean.cv.errors)],
       col="red",cex=2,pch=20)

reg.best=regsubsets (selfaware~.,data=best_demo_train)
coef(reg.best ,3) 
reg.summary=summary(reg.best ,3)
reg.summary$adjr2
```

So, once I have the "best" variables, I would like to "test" that model on 20% of the data. Can someone help me out with this? I do not know what the script would be to test this model and have been unsuccessful searching online.

Thank you, I appreciate it. 
Sarah